# Sed command not working in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, sed, jenkins-pipeline

I have a file 'README.txt' which contains the line -

> "version": "1.0.0-alpha-test.7"

Using a Jenkins Pipeline, I want to replace this line with

```
"version": "1.0.0-alpha-test.{BUILD_NUMBER}"
```

The following sed command works when I try it on a linux cluster

```
sed -i -E "s#(\"version\"[ ]*:[ ]*\".+alpha-test\.)[0-9]+\"#\1${BUILD_NUMBER}#g" README.txt
```

The same command does not work using a Jenkins Pipeline.

Tried with the following query but it doesn't work -

```
sh """
sed -i -E "s|([\"]version[\"][ ]*:[ ]*[\"].+alpha-test\\.)[0-9]+\"|\1${BUILD_NUMBER}|g" README.txt
cat README.txt
"""
```

> /home/jenkins/workspace/test/test-pipeline@tmp/durable-eb774fcf/script.sh:
>   3:
>   /home/jenkins/workspace/test/test-pipeline@tmp/durable-eb774fcf/script.sh:
>   Syntax error: ")" unexpected

Comment: You **say** you want `{BUILD_NUMBER}` in the output but your code is trying to insert `${BUILD_NUMBER}` - what should really appear in the output - the text `{BUILD_NUMER}` or the value of the shell variable `${BUILD_NUMBER}` or something else?

Comment: Syntax errors are 99% caused by bad escapes or no escapes. Using QUOTES within TRIPLE QUOTES will usually trip you up.  Replace them with single ticks. `"` to `'` for the sed command:
`sed -i -E 's|([\"]version[\"][ ]*:[ ]*[\"].+alpha-test\\.)[0-9]+\"|\1${BUILD_NUMBER}|g' README.txt
cat README.txt`

Answer (score -3):

Best to use perl command instead...

```
script{

old_version = (sh (returnStdout: true, script:'''old_version=`cat version.cfg |grep VERSION=|cut -d "=" -f2`
echo $old_version''')).toString().trim()

sh """

     if [ "$old_version" != $new_version ]; then
        perl -pi -e "s,$old_version,$new_version,g" version.cfg
        ##-- git push operation --##
     fi  

"""

}
```